# Not getting focus on table tag via keyboard

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am having trouble getting focus on my table and i am not sure how i should mark it up so it could get access via keyboard.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="sortable" width="10%" (click)="onHeaderClick('id')"
                            [ngClass]="{'active': sortBy == 'id', 'ascending': sortOrder == 'asc', 'descending': sortOrder == 'desc'}">
                            Id
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="sortable" width="50%" (click)="onHeaderClick('name')"
                            [ngClass]="{'active': sortBy == 'name', 'ascending': sortOrder == 'asc', 'descending': sortOrder == 'desc'}">
                            Name
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let student of studentList" (click)="selectedStudent(student)">
                        <td>
                            {{student.uId}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a (click)="profile(student)">{{student.fields.Name}}</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `button` elements inside the table header cells instead of trying to make the `th` elements themselves interactive.

Buttons are designed to be interacted with and come with all the affordences to help the user work with them.

Comment: do you mean doing this: <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <button scope="col" class="sortable" width="10%" (click)="onHeaderClick('id')"
                            [ngClass]="{'active': sortBy == 'id', 'ascending': sortOrder == 'asc', 'descending': sortOrder == 'desc'}">
                            Id
                        </button>

Comment: No. **inside** the `th` not *instead of*.

Comment: i am having some trouble picturing this out - is it possible to paste a sample code of what you mean.

Comment: `<th><button> ... </button></th>`

Comment: I am getting focus on it now but i will have to create a class that will stripe away the button styling for this...

Comment: is adding a button the only solution?

Comment: in the <tbody> i have each <tr> as a clickable row - where the user can click on that row and it will navigate them to that detailed page. Is the button feature also required to get that same functionality?